# Alignment of h1 and p tag on CSS sheet in HTML

Tags: html, css, alignment, center

I am trying to align my an "h1" tag and a "p" tag that both are around an  tag.  I am trying to only center those along with the image that I have centered.  I am trying to only do this on the CSS sheet and not on the HTML file itself.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: gray;
}

h1 i {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

p i {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 80%;
}

p::first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1><i>The Charge of the Light Brigade</i></h1>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/FSXhJNy.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />
<p><i>By Tennyson</i></p>
<h1>I.</h1>
<p>Half a league, half a league, Half a league onward, All in the valley of Death Rode the six hundred. 'Forward, the Light Brigade!' 'Charge for the guns!' he said: Into the valley of Death Rode the six hundred.</p>
<h1>II.</h1>
<p>'Forward, the Light Brigade!' Was there a man dismay'd? Not tho' the soldier knew Some one had blunder'd: Their's not to make reply, Their's not to reason why, Their's but to do and die: Into the valley of Death Rode the six hundred.</p>
<h1>III.</h1>
```

Comment: You do not mention what's going wrong; anyway, `<i>` is an inline tag, not a block tag, and I see no way of centering an inline tag.

Comment: I am just trying to get the very first h1 tag and the p tag with the Author's name centered but am unable to with the CSS sheet.  I apologize for not posting that originally.

Comment: You define a `text-align: left` for `<p>`. As I mentioned above I do not see what defining `text-align: center` for `<p><i>` should mean, as `<i>` is an inline tag. How should an inline tag be centered? If you do not want *all* `<p>` tags to be centered, define a `class=` for centered paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: left;
  color: gray;
}

p i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-right: 80%;
}

p::first-letter {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-style: bold;
}

.center{
 color: black;
    margin-left: 25%;
    font-size: 39px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  The Charge of the Light Brigade
 </div>

 
 <img src="http://i.imgur.com/FSXhJNy.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" />
 <p>
  <i>By Tennyson</i>
 </p>
 
 <h1>I.</h1>
 
 <p>Half a league, half a league, Half a league onward, All in the valley of Death Rode the six hundred. 'Forward, the Light Brigade!' 'Charge for the guns!' he said: Into the valley of Death Rode the six hundred.</p>
 
 <h1>II.</h1>
 
 <p>'Forward, the Light Brigade!' Was there a man dismay'd? Not tho' the soldier knew Some one had blunder'd: Their's not to make reply, Their's not to reason why, Their's but to do and die: Into the valley of Death Rode the six hundred.</p>
 
 <h1>III.</h1>
```